# How can I make a mutable list of mutable maps?

Tags: kotlin

My attempt:

```
val areas = mutableListOf<mutableMapOf<Double, Double>()>()
```

On `mutableListOf` it shows an error `Function invocation 'mutableListOf(...)' expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutableMapOf<Double, Double>()` is a function call that creates a map. You need to first create a list and only specify the type of its items, which is: `MutableMap<Double, Double>`:

```kotlin
val areas = mutableListOf<MutableMap<Double, Double>>()
```

Then you can add maps to it:

```kotlin
areas += mutableMapOf(1.0 to 1.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code to add maps because my known `areas.add(1.0 to 1.0)` doesn't work in the way I want to.